# Difference between getting an Object using FetchResultController and ManagedObjectContext

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext

What's the difference between get elements from Core Data with FetchResultController or ManagedObjectContext??

1) FetchResultController

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init]; 
[fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext]]; 

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorNameAscending = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptorNameAscending,nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
[sortDescriptorNameAscending release];

NSFetchedResultsController *frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Lists"];
```

2) ManagedObjectContext

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init]; 
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Item"  inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]]; 
NSError *error = nil; 
NSArray *items = [ managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point behind using an `NSFetchedResultsController` as opposed to just a `NSFetchRequest` is the monitoring of your data and the convenience methods when working with sections.

When dealing with just a `NSFetchRequest` you have to determine the sections yourself and you need to refetch your data when something changes.

When dealing with the `NSFetchedResultsController`, it will determine your sections, cache the results (making a second request for that data near instantaneous), and provide convenience methods for your NSTableView.  Finally, when your data changes, the `NSFetchedResultsController` will notify you through its delegates.

The data internal to both of these is going to be the same.  It is managing the state of that data that is the difference.

Answer (score 0):

The `NSFetchedResultsController` object will tell you when the objects of your query change. Just provide a delegate object to receive the calls (see the doc for `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` protocol).
It also provide you with section management which is useful if you want to display the data in a table view.

Comment: Thanks. But the Array returned by this two methods are the same, aren't they?? The questions is about it: the difference about the return. I tested after asking and I think it is.